# How would you specify a grammar that can parse letters separated by single underscores?

Tags: formal-grammars, parsers

In JavaScript, let's say, it is easy to build a string intermixed with single underscores by just *joining* the string parts.

```
let string = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].join('_')
```

In addition, it is straightforward to write a grammar that can have letters separated by **at least one** underscore.

```
grammar = letter letterOrUnderscore*
letter = a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z
underscore = _
letterOrUnderscore = underscore|letter
```

That will match the input string:

```
foo_bar_baz
```

However, it will also match these unwanted strings:

```
a____
ab__c
abc__d___
```

Basically, it will match *sequences of underscores*, when what we want is *only one underscore between each sequence of letters*, and we shouldn't have trailing underscores. So only these are acceptable, for example:

```
a
ab_c
abc_d
```

The question is, how do you define a grammar to only allow **1 underscore between each sequence of letters**? I can't figure out how to write any sort of custom "grammar DSL" that can, in a straightforward way, handle this situation... I'm stumped currently how to do this.

```
grammar = letter then
  if previous == letter
    next = letter | underscore
  else
    next = letter
```

So it seems to need to access to the previous state, is there no other way to define this? Besides not being very "DSL-like", it's also significantly harder to handle this sort of situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is a regular language, so describing it with a regular expression would be a good approach.

Another way to view the language is one word, followed by zero or more (underscore word) sequences.

In PCRE syntax, `[a-z]+(_[a-z]+)*`.

The same idea can be used to remove left recursion from some grammars; instead of a production rule like $E \to E + E$ (expressions can be combined with plus), you use $E \to T S$ with $S \to \varepsilon; S \to + T S$ (terms can be followed by zero or more "operations", which is an operator followed by a term)